# Creating a template file for one specific page created by a custom module

Tags: theming

How do I call a custom theme file (stored in the theme folder) that displays on a specific page that is created by a module.

It's a module for viewing mortgages in a full-page view. The template file is called page--single_view.tpl.php

The module is named single_view and has these functions:

```
<?php 
/**
 * @file
 * Single Mortgage Views module file
 */

 /**
 * hook_menu() add to menu
 */
 function mortgage_single_view_menu() {

  $items = array();

  $items['mortgage/%/view'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'single_view_theme', //This isn't correct but just set this way for now
    'page argument' => array(3), //pass 3rd argument of url -- 1. drupal 2. mortgage 3. %
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
 }

 /*
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */

function single_view_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array (
    'page__single_view' => array (
      'variables' => array(),
      'template' => 'page--single_view' ,
      'base hook' => 'page',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'single_view'),
    ),
  );
}
```

I'm guessing my implementation of hook_theme isn't correct. The page that comes up is just blank?

Comment: Why is your implementation of `hook_menu` called `mortgage_single_view_menu`? If your module is called single_view, then your implementation of hook_menu should be `single_view_menu`.  Also, you're using hook_theme all wrong.  It is not meant to be a page callback.  Will see if I have time to write up the right way to do it.

Comment: I corrected that single_view hook_menu. I typed it wrong in here but it was correct in my .module file. 

Per @gnuget answer below I changed the callback to a callback function which then calls the theme() function and passes it the key and $variables? I'm so confused about how to use these theme hooks lol

Comment: Work on getting the page callback returning something before you tackle using theme functions properly.  Don't make life unnecessarily difficult for yourself. Also: your `page argument` value should be `array(1)` if it's your intention to pass the value of the % placeholder to your page callback.

Comment: The first step should just be getting the page to work at all; try to have your callback just do `return array();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't pass the single_view_theme as a page callback.

create a new function with something like this:

```
function single_view_callback($something) {
  return theme('page__single_view', $variables);
}
```

And in your page callback replace 'single_view_theme' with 'single_view_callback'.

Comment: Hmmmm so it's still coming up as a blank page (cleared the caches just incase).

Should I keep my hook_theme() function in there as is?

Comment: I tried to add the callback function but the page still comes up blank after clearing caches.

Comment: Blank pages can be caused by errors; make sure you've taken the steps you need to take to make them visible.  Easiest way is adding these lines to index.php: (from: https://www.drupal.org/node/158043)

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
`

The recommendations by Gnuget should be working (assuming you did not copy-paste them exactly).